# No add wizard option for Report Viewer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: report, visual-studio-2017

Any reason why there is no option to create a new report in Visual Studio 2017?

in previous VS version, I used to have the option to "**Design a new report**". Now it's gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, right click on the folder you want to add a report to and click the "Add New Report" option. This takes you to the Wizard.